# how to connect a Wiimote device to Windows 8 without knowing the pairing code

Tags: windows-8, bluetooth, dongle, wii, wiimote

I have a CSR bluetooth radio, a bluetooth dongle. I'm trying to connect my wiimote to my laptop. Whenever I try to connect it, it asks for the pairing code, but (after searching online) it turns out that a pairing code isn't needed to connect the wiimote to the laptop through bluetooth. I also don't get the option to skip this step.

The steps that I take:

- I go to bluetooth, right-click and click add device.
- I search for my wiimote and on the wiimote I press sync.
- When they both find each other, I double-click on the found device (the wiimote) and it asks me for the pairing code.

[image]

There is no option to skip this step. I've tried to connect with 0000, 1111, 1234, but none of them seems to work.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of your Bluetooth management program.

Comment: I tried, but since I don't have enough reputation it won't allow me. (I have edited it with a link to a screenshot)

Comment: Everyone can include *links* to images.

Comment: What happens if you click on the link that say's "What must I do if I can't find the pairing code"? I hope I've translated the Dutch correctly  - after living in Holland for 6 years I still have only very basic Dutch :/

Comment: It just sends me to a page that basically just says that theh device either has a paring code that I should look for or I should try one of the default pairing codes 1111 or 0000. - and yes you've translated it correctly :)

Answer (score 1):

The pin is your WiiMote's MAC address backwards. Use one of the following ways to find it:

> If connecting by holding down the 1+2 buttons, the PIN is the bluetooth address of the wiimote backwards, if connecting by pressing the “sync” button on the back of the wiimote, then the PIN is the bluetooth address of the host backwards.

- [Using Microsoft Windows and BlueSoleil](http://android.ccpcreations.com/wiicontroller/wc-findmac-bs)
- [Bluetooth MAC Finder Android App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ccpcreations.android.bluetoothmacfinder&hl=en)
- [Wiimote added to USB Host library](http://blog.tkjelectronics.dk/2012/08/wiimote-added-to-usb-host-library/)
- [Wii Remote Plus (RVL-CNT-01-TR) Connection Guide](https://wiki.dolphin-emu.org/index.php?title=Wii_Remote_Plus_(RVL-CNT-01-TR)_Connection_Guide)